# How to make SnackBar width flexible based on text in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, snackbar

`Snackbar` width can only be set with parameter width, otherwise it uses full screen width.

Is there a way I can make it flexible?

EDIT: Something like this below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using a toast instead should work better for you. Since the image you shared looks like a toast message and not a snackbar.

Comment: This is a snackbar with custom color and width.

Comment: is there a solution with snackbar and AutosizedText ?  and not with flutter toast

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tricky way without using packages:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
  SnackBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0,
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
    behavior: SnackBarBehavior.floating,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 76.0),
    content: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Card(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 12.0),
              child: Text(text),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a very useful package that you can use- [fluttertoast](https://pub.dev/packages/fluttertoast).

Simply write -

```
Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "This is Center Short Toast",
    );
```

You can add `toastLength` to make it short or long -

```
Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "This is Center Short Toast",
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
    );
```

Hope this helps. Let me know.

Answer (score -2):

other solution is use [oktoast](https://pub.dev/packages/oktoast), we can change position with position parameter

```
showToast(
      "$_counter",
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      position: ToastPosition.bottom,
      backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
      radius: 13.0,
      textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
    );
```